# how to sort a pandas df after a specific index value?

Tags: sorting, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("00:00", "04:00", freq="1H").time,data={'column1':[0,1,2,3,4]})
```

To begin with we have the following df:

```
          column1
00:00:00        0
01:00:00        1
02:00:00        2
03:00:00        3
04:00:00        4
```

How do we sort from a specific index value in an ascending order, e.g. from 03:00:00?

Desired output:

```
          column1
03:00:00        3
04:00:00        4
00:00:00        0
01:00:00        1
02:00:00        2
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the only answer I could think of, but maybe someone is aware of a more elegant approach

```
df.loc[np.concatenate([np.array(df.index[3:]),np.array(df.index[:3])])]

          column1
03:00:00        3
04:00:00        4
00:00:00        0
01:00:00        1
02:00:00        2
```